# Regex captures unwanted characters on repeated group

Tags: regex

Subsequent captures for a group are including the comma or the closing parenthesis.

**The regex:**

```
(?<name1>\?\?\$.*)\s\((?<type1>\w+)\s(?<conv>\w+)\s(?<name2>\w+:?:?)+<(?<type2>[\w\s]+)>\((?<args>.+?(?=[,)]))+\)
```

**The input:**

```
??$PlotBarGroups@C@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBCHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<signed char>(char const * const * const,signed char const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@E@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBEHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<unsigned char>(char const * const * const,unsigned char const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@F@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBFHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<short>(char const * const * const,short const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@G@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBGHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<unsigned short>(char const * const * const,unsigned short const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@H@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBHHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<int>(char const * const * const,int const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@I@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBIHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<unsigned int>(char const * const * const,unsigned int const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@M@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBMHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<float>(char const * const * const,float const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@N@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPBNHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<double>(char const * const * const,double const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@_J@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPB_JHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<__int64>(char const * const * const,__int64 const *,int,int,double,double,int))
??$PlotBarGroups@_K@ImPlot@@YAXQBQBDPB_KHHNNH@Z (void __cdecl ImPlot::PlotBarGroups<unsigned __int64>(char const * const * const,unsigned __int64 const *,int,int,double,double,int))
```

**Actual result:**

```
signed char
char const * const * const
,signed char const *
,int
,int
,double
,double
,int
)
```

**Expected result:**

```
signed char
char const * const * const
signed char const *
int
int
double
double
int
```

**Online sample:**

https://regex101.com/r/Fkyk4P/1

**Question:**

How can I not capture these commas and closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```bash
(?<name1>\?{0,2}\$.*)\s\((?<type1>\w+)\s(?<conv>\w+)\s(?<name2>\w+:{0,2})+<(?<type2>[\w\s]+)>\((?: *(?<args>[^,)]+)[,)])+
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Fkyk4P/2)

Take note of last repeating capture group:

```bash
(?: *(?<args>[^,)]+)[,)])+
```

That matches 1+ of non-comma, non-`)` characters which must be followed by `,` or `)`.

Or if we want to make this regex more strict then use:

```bash
(?<name1>\?{0,2}\$.*)\s\((?<type1>\w+)\s(?<conv>\w+)\s(?<name2>\w+:{0,2})+<(?<type2>[\w\s]+)>\( *(?<args>[^,)]+)(?:, *(?<args>[^,)]+))*\)
```

Here last subpattern is:

```bash
\( *(?<args>[^,)]+)(?:, *(?<args>[^,)]+))*\)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Fkyk4P/3)

Comment: I got it now, the key is to enclose both things into a non-capturing group!